# Can not access CiviCRM

Tags: payment-processor

I cannot access CiviCRNM on Drupal. I get

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Could not find user name for payment processor

Return to home page.

I am using drupal 7 and civiCRM 4.6.3. I had made some changes to the set event as payable when creating an earlier event and used dummy credentials for paypal pro. I now do not know how to undo the changes or gain access to CiviCRM. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to specify exactly which civicrm pages you are unable to access?

Comment: Phillip. Thank you. You answer worked for me. I then went back and added the complete PayPal details and it seems to work. Intially, I only added the test gateway details and had the box default payment gateway ticked. Perhaps this was the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply commented out the line requiring the payment processor and it worked. I then deleted the payment processor I had created earlier.Finally. I uncommented the line I had previously commented out.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access civicrm backoffice?

Try http://yoursite.org/civicrm/admin and disable the payment processor from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not access http://yoursite.org/civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor?reset=1 disable the processor via db by setting the `is_active` field to `0` inside table `civicrm_payment_processor`.